# Not Able to install gems in Rails 2.3.8 & Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

**First Of all Thanks in advance :)**

---

When I try to install the gem in rails application so it shows error like below.

```
 $ rake gems:install
Invalid gemspec in [/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/specifications/carmen-1.0.0.beta2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f630b62a000> 2.6.1"]
rake aborted!
undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/aspireedge/Aspiree/pyromaniac/config/environment.rb:16
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when I try to update gem

```
    $ gem update --system

Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

I aslo try to remove gem with `rvm gemset empty`

but still got error

Comment: Does sudo gem install carmen -v1.0.0.beta2 work?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade your RubyGems and remove and install again the carmen gem:

```
gem update --system
gem uninstall carmen
gem install carmen
```

There is a PPA with up-to-date versions of Ruby 2.x for Ubuntu 14.04+:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove rubygems
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.4

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: I do but It saw  Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

Comment: @RBhatt to delete the gems

Comment: it shows like this @Roshan gem install carmen
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing carmen:
 concurrent-ruby requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.

Comment: @RBhatt what os are you using ? It seems that you need to upgrade your ruby version.

Comment: i use ubuntu 14.10 64bit

Comment: @RBhatt i have added guide to install latest ruby on ubuntu

Comment: i want ruby 1.8.7 not 2.4

Comment: @RBhatt if you understand what your error says, it needs `requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3` . If you need to stick to `ruby 1.8.7`, then you might need to downgrade certain gems to satisfy it.

Comment: i want to setup my old project so i wnat to stick on ruby 1.8.7 @Roshan

Comment: @RBhatt then start downgrade some of the gem.